# Jquery same id more jobs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsfiddle

I don't know how i can explain my problem, but ill write my code here:

```
<span class="imdb" id="nota_imdb" data-value="18"></span>
<span class="imdb" id="nota_imdb" data-value="19"></span>
<span class="imdb" id="nota_imdb" data-value="20"></span>

<script>
var title = $("#nota_imdb").attr( "data-value" );
$( "#imdb" ).text( title );
</script>
```

I have same id but diferent atribute for write.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take `data-value` attribute value and use it as text for current element.

1. Don't use same `id`s, use `class` instead
2. `$(".imdb")` will get a list of nodes, you can iterate through them via `.each()`
3. Pass callback function inside `.each()` and use the second parameter to get the current node

```js
$(".imdb").each(function(i, item) {
  var title = $(item).attr("data-value");
  $(item).text(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="imdb" data-value="18"></span>
<span class="imdb" data-value="19"></span>
<span class="imdb" data-value="20"></span>
```

PS: If you want help on SO, you need to formulate the problem clearly.

Comment: thank you very very much. if i could explain the problem i do but I'm just a nob!!